# Delegate Android activity result to other activity

Tags: java, android, android-activity

I have the following scenario:

1. My `MainActivity` class launches `InputActivity1` using `startActivityForResult` with the request code `SOME_USER_INPUT`.
2. `InputActivity1` lets the user input some data and then passes this data to `InputActivity2` using `Intent.putExtra`.
3. In `InputActivity2` the user can input some more data.
4. By calling `setResult` and `finish` in `InputActivity2`, all data the user entered shall be returned to the `onActivityResult` method of `MainActivity` with the previously specified request code `SOME_USER_INPUT`.

That is, `MainActivity` shall not notice at all that the result comes from `InputActivity2`, although it just called `InputActivity1`.

How can I do the transition from step 2 to 3? I already tried starting `InputActivity2` from `InputActivity1` by calling `startActivityForResult` with the request code and `finish`, but (admittedly as expected) `MainActivity` does not receive anything.

Comment: Can you share your code ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't call finish in InputActivity1 after calling startActivity (InputActivity2). Do it only when you get the results from InputActivity2. In that way you can pass the results from InputActivit2 to MainActivitiy.

I guess, you can implement this with One InputActivity with two fragments. Just think.

Comment: Thank you, this worked great. The solution can be so easy sometimes! And I know that you can implement it differently, I am currently just trying out various things with activities to practice a little bit ;)